# Access variable that was overwritten within given scope via function that uses global variables

Tags: c++, c, function, scope, global-variables

I have this piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// global variable definition
int x = 0;

void access_global(){
    cout << "ACCESSING FROM access_global()" << endl;
    if (x > 0){
        cout << "LOCAL VARIABLE" << endl;
        cout << x << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "GLOBAL VARIABLE" << endl;
        cout << x << endl;
    }
}


int main(int, char*[])
{
    // declare new variable in given scope with same name as global variable
    int x = 1;

    cout << "ACCESSING FROM main()" << endl;
    if (x > 0){
        cout << "LOCAL VARIABLE" << endl;
        cout << x << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "GLOBAL VARIABLE" << endl;
        cout << x << endl;
    }

    access_global();

    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
ACCESSING FROM main()
LOCAL VARIABLE
1
ACCESSING FROM access_global()
GLOBAL VARIABLE
0
```

Why is `access_global()` not accessing `x` in the `main()` scope?
Is  it possible to modify `access_global()` function that it will show primary `x` variables from `main()` scope and if they are not defined then show those defined outside of `main()`? If is not possible can you please explain why? Thanks

Comment: please clarify why I've been down voted. Thanks

Comment: Local variables inside a function or if/else, loops cannot be accessed from outside. It's not like namespaces.

Comment: @Raindrop7 what do you mean by "it's not like namespaces". Can you post some link or clarify this in answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is `access_global()` not accessing `x` in the `main()` scope?

Because `main::x` is not in scope in `access_global`. Fortunately, names don't just "leak" out of functions' scopes. The global `x` is the only `x` it can see.

> Is it possible to modify `access_global()` function that it will show primary `x` variables from `main()` scope and if they are not defined then show those defined outside of `main()`?

Not in the way you are hoping to, no. The names in `main` are not related to the names in `access_global` in any sense.

> If is not possible can you please explain why?

As usual: Because the standard says so. Why it does that is subject to some speculation, but it would certainly be *extremely* confusing if the meaning of some function changed depending on what names exist in the calling context, something you usually don't control when writing a function.

Just think what would happen if `access_global` was called once from a function that has some `x`, possibly not even of type `int`, and once from some function that does not have a local `x`: You could not predict what the function does at all without looking at all callers. That's very much impractical.